# Writing data into SQL Server database - Invalid object name error

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am working with an excel file that holds macros. In these macros, a connection to a SQL Server database is created and data is loaded from the sheets in the Excel file into the tables in the database.

This file is used by multiple users.

Currently, we have an issue where writing data into the db works for some users while other users get the following Run-time error:

> [Microsoft][OBDS SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name
> "TableName".

The connection to SQL Server in the macro is specified as following:

```
'Setting the connection

Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
oConn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL server};" & _
    "server=" & ServerName & ";authenticateduser=TRUE;database=" & DatabaseName
oConn.Open
```

The table definitely exists in the db and as mentioned, other users don't receive that error message.

What could be the issue that makes the connection work for some users while others get the error?

Comment: Database or table is not accessible for some users?

Comment: Check security settings.

Comment: Check the actual values that you embed in the connection string and verify that they are correct. Perhaps that "user" is not connecting to the appropriate server instance or database.

Comment: Where's the code that actually throws the error? I'm guessing you're trying to build an SQL Query dynamically by concatenating string segments together much as you are with the connection string.

Comment: The code that throws the error is the part when they write data to the database using an sql string: oConn.Execute SQLStr

Comment: Also I should probably add that despite the error, data is written into the table (through oConn.Execute SQLStr).